# How to implement chat message unread count as we get in whatsapp ? Please suggest me some way to implement message unread count in android

Tags: android

How to implement chat message unread count as we get in whatsapp ? Please suggest me some way to implement message unread count in android .

I am using Php MySql and firebase in backend .

Please give me some way through which i can display unread message count in andoroid app ?

[unread message count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdiqV.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Its not so difficult as you are stating about the logic.